# How to Set up JavaCV for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, build.gradle, javacv

I am trying to implement these techniques and algorithms: **Image Filtering, Edge Detection, Image Binarization, Contour Detection, Cell Segmentation** using **JavaCV**

But I don't know how to set up JavaCV for specifically for android but at ***GitHub*** of **JavaCV** documentation provide this **Gradle:**

```
     dependencies {
            implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5.8'
         }
```

Which include all jar file for different platform but in this case only jar file for android is required.

I downloaded the **javacv-platform-1.5.8-bin.zip** file and try to copy the jar file to libs folder in Android studio project but there is no file name **javacv-android-arm.jar** in **javacv-platform-1.5.8-bin.zip**.

So if someone can help me locate which jar file is required and how i can add then correctly or how to set up *Android Studio Project* for **javaCV**

Thanks.

**Version: *****Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2***
**Android Gradle Plugin Version:** 7.3.1
**Gradle Version:** 7.4

**I tired adding different jar file but few of the function and method are not able to import into the project**
**Error:** *Rename Reference*

Comment: That's what Gradle JavaCPP's Platform Plugin is for: https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#the-platform-plugin

Comment: can you guide little more what should i add maybe in steps that will be very helpful. I am beginner @SamuelAudet

Comment: You can start from this sample project: https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/tree/master/JavaCV-android-example

Answer (score 2):

adding this bit to the app's `build.gradle` seems to do the trick:

```
configurations {
    javacpp
}

task javacppExtract(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn configurations.javacpp

    from { configurations.javacpp.collect { zipTree(it) } }
    include "lib/**"
    into "$buildDir/javacpp/"
    android.sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs += ["$buildDir/javacpp/lib/"]

    tasks.getByName('preBuild').dependsOn javacppExtract
}

dependencies {

    ... original ...

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.5.9'
    javacpp group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas-platform', version: '0.3.23-1.5.9'
    javacpp group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv-platform', version: '4.7.0-1.5.9'
    javacpp group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg-platform', version: '6.0-1.5.9'
}
```